# Bi-directional communication between Google Assistant and my App

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, android-contacts, google-assistant-sdk

Firstly, I will note my observations of how other apps use Google Assistant (GA) with their android apps installed on local devices:

When you use apps like WhatsApp & Telegram (with a locally installed version on your device), it allows you to send a message via GA.

You’re able to do the following:

- Select a desired contact (from what looks like the device’s phone book)
- Add a text message and send it.

[image]

From my research I have come across these posts which suggest how they possibly achieve this:

- https://github.com/iNPUTmice/Conversations/issues/2655
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.html#ACTION_VOICE_SEND_MESSAGE_TO_CONTACTS
- http://aivc.mobi/en/questions/view/8/whatsapp-message
- https://github.com/GigaDroid/Decompiled-Whatsapp/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml
- https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

I chatted to @prisoner and he indicated that in this case GA is handing off the responsibility to the local app to complete the request. Which sort of makes sense based on the links I found.

In my case, I’m integrating my android application with Google Assistant and DialogFlow.

Thus far, I’ve managed to setup intents and fulfilment in DialogFlow which can be trigged by GA on a device.

I have a few questions regarding other functionality I’d like to achieve. Should I:

1. Either use GA and my local app to complete requests?
2. Or use GA, DialogFlow and my server (using a web-hook) to complete my requests?

To be able to achieve either of the two points above, I need to answer the below questions, assuming i'm using [Actions-on-Google](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/index.html):

1. Is it possible to achieve bi-directional communication between my local app and GA?
2. Is there a mechanism I can use to expose data within my local app to GA? E.g. a list that will be displayed within GA which the user can interact with.
3. Or rather should I authenticate my user using (Google Sign-in & OAuth) and fetch my data from the server (using a web-hook) through GA and DialogFlow?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Reddit user fleker2](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/gdyi7f/bidirectional_communication_between_ga_android_app/) bi-directional communication between Google Assistant and the app is only possible using [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview):

> For communication between a local app and the Assistant, you can look
>   at using [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview). Note that the capabilities are within a few
>   domains, and not generally applicable.
>   If you are asking whether to use a local app versus Dialogflow, consider your audience. A webhook and server would work on more surfaces like a Google Home or smart display.
>
> You cannot have arbitrary communication between Assistant and a local
>   app. If an app action doesn't work, you'll need a way to route webhook
>   behavior to your app or service in a custom way.

Unfortunately App Actions are not mature enough for our use case.